Rename-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (flutter upgrade)
I want to upgrade the version of flutter SDK but I got the error:
Rename-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Android\flutter\bin\internal\update_dart_sdk.ps1:74 char:9
+         Rename-Item $dartSdkPath "$oldDartSdkPrefix$oldDartSdkSuffix"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Android\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Error: Unable to update Dart SDK. Retrying... 

I have first tried flutter upgrade and then I tried flutter upgrade --force but I got same error in --force too.
Is there any way to upgrade flutter version?

it says that another flutter command is running on your pc, do you have open vscode / android studio or whatever ide?

btw if you want to upgrade the flutter and keep different versions or stable / beta channels use https://puro.dev/reference/manual/

Yes I know it says another process is running but I've checked no other process is running.

how did you do that?

I have checked no instances of Flutter, Dart, or any related IDEs (like Android Studio or VS Code) are running in background.

tried to reboot and immediately after rebooting call flutter upgrade?

Okay I tried it and it works. Thank you @pskink

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
